# 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Selection'

Tags: c#, ms-word

I unfortunately do not understand how to get Selection. I checked msdn and from what I can tell I'm probably missing a reference or something.The code itself is to replace words found in a template when you fill out a forms box. Pretty simple and straight forward.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Word.Application objWord = new Word.Application();
        objWord.Visible = true;
        object isVisible = true;
        object readOnly = false;
        Word.Document objDoc;
        object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object fileName = @"C:\Users\jason\Documents\Custom Office Templates\MLA1.dotx";
        objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref Missing, ref  readOnly, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref isVisible, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing);

    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void SearchReplace()
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        Word.Find findObject = Application.Selection.Find;
        findObject.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Text = "Name";
        findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Replacement.Text = textBox1.Text;

        object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

     }
     }
     }
```

Comment: Move `objWord` declaration outside the `Form1` constructor and use `objWord.Selection.Find` instead

Comment: Fantastic! that worked. However, any idea how to make it change text in a Header too? Haven't looked into it yet and no worries if you don't want to answer that. That will be my next search tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application` is a class name (although you have aliased in this case, so the correct class name is `Word.Application`).

`Selection` is an instance property of this class, so it can only be accessed via an instance.  You have an instance, `objWord`.  If you declared this as an instance field in your form, then you could access it from your button click handler:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Word.Application objWord;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objWord = new Word.Application();
        // ...
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Word.Find findObject = objWord.Selection.Find;
        // ...
    }
```

As an aside, as of C# 4 the `ref` and all the parameters are optional for COM Interop.  So this line:

```
objWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref Missing, ref  readOnly, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref isVisible, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing);
```

Can be written as below, making use of optional and named arguments:

```
objWord.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: readOnly, IsVisible: isVisible);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the Word instance in a field of your `Form1` class so that you can later on access it in the button event handler:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Word.Application _wordApplication;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _wordApplication = new Word.Application();
        _wordApplication.Visible = true;

        var fileName = @"C:\Users\jason\Documents\Custom Office Templates\MLA1.dotx";
        var document = _wordApplication.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly:false, Visible: true);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var findObject = _wordApplication.Selection.Find;
        findObject.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Text = "Name";
        findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Replacement.Text = textBox1.Text;

        object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        findObject.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
    }
}
```